# Find the range of index of consecutive integers from a sorted array

Tags: java, algorithm

I would like to know how can   improve  my solution.

```
import java.util.*;
public class prog{

    public   Map<Integer, Integer>  findList(int[] array1)
    {
         Map<Integer, Integer> list= new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

         int start_index= 0;
         int end_index = 0;
         int length = array1.length; 

         for(int i = 1; i < length ; ++i)            
         {            
             if(array1[i-1] + 1 != array1[i])
             {

                 end_index = i - 1;
                 list.put(start_index, end_index);
                 start_index = i;
             }   
         }                
         if( array1[length -2]+1 == array1[length -1])
         {
             end_index = length - 1;
             list.put(start_index, end_index);
         }
          return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arr)
    {
        int [] array1 = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 22, 23, 24, 27,34 };
        prog prg = new prog();
        Map<Integer, Integer> list1= new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        list1 = prg.findList(array1);

        for( Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry: list1.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println( entry.getKey()+"--"+ entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Correctness:**

Your code doesn't seem to actually produce the correct answer.

When I ran this code, I got:

0--5
6--6
7--10
11--11
12--14
15--15

However... the list has 17 elements, so 16--16 is missing.

The reason for this is that once you are done with the `for` loop, you do handle the case when the last two elements are part of a consecutive range, but in your test case, they aren't.

The way to fix this is very easy: remove the `if`. It should look like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < length ; ++i) {            
    // same as yours
}                
end_index = length - 1;
list.put(start_index, end_index);

return list;
```

**Style:**

Aside from the things that Mayur already mentioned,

- Comment your code. It took me many more minutes than it should have to figure out what it does.
- Along the same vein, name things according to what they do. For example, I would rename `findList` (A completely pointless name... might as well have been foobar) to `buildConsecutiveRangeMap`. I would also change `array1` to `numbers`, or at least drop the unnecessary "1". Lastly, `prog` is just a completely meaningless name for a class...rethink this.
- Make " "'s matter. Why do you have extra spaces between `public` and `Map`? `>` and `findList`? Right before the `return`? At the same time, you could use more to make `length -2` into `length - 2`, `array[index]+1` into `array[index] + 1` and so on.
- Don't prematurely optimize. That's the only reason I could see for using another variable to store `array1.length` instead of using that everywhere. Little secret: It's just a field lookup that takes O(1) time and a modern day JIT will notice that that value is constant and optimize your loop for you.
- Import just the things you need. It's a waste to include everything under the sun.

**Other comments**

- Test, test, test. Testing would have led you to find the bug and helps developers figure out what you are trying to accomplish based on the expected output.
- To clean things up, I suggest checking if the range is something like 15--15 and instead just print 15.
- Don't waste your time allocating things when you don't need to. You allocate some memory for `list1` in `main` and then in the `findList` method, you allocate some more. The garbage collector will of course clean this up...but it also makes your code uglier. Just replace your
  code in main with:

`Map<Integer, Integer> rangeMap = findList(numbers);`

- Another feature you might want is to print the numbers in order. The fact that the results happened to be in order is coincidence. A `Map` guarantees nothing about order and it is up to you to sort the data as you like. Testing different numbers and larger data sets will make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Style**

Java coder usually use this style :

```
public void someFuntion(){
   //something here
}
```

Instead of C like style

```
public void someFunction
{
  //something 
}
```

**Static Methods**

You used following line in your code

```
prog prg = new prog();
```

You don't need to instantiate unnecessarily, instead you should make use of static methods, so a correct definition would be

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer>  findList(int[] array1)
```

**Naming conventions**

Java uses Pascal Notation for classes and Camel Notation for methods. So, your class name should start with a capital letter.

Eg : `public class MyLinkedList`, `public class SomeRelevantName`

And, function name should begin with lower case, which you have already used.

**Misc**

1. Proper spacing should be used to improve readability eg :
   `System.out.println(someIntValue + " = " + anotherIntValue);`
2. Newlines should be used systematically and throughout the code, eg: 2 Newlines after end of every function, one newline before the class ends etc.